# Upload to S3 with progress in plain Ruby script

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-sdk, progress

This question is related to this one: [Tracking Upload Progress of File to S3 Using Ruby aws-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12085751/tracking-upload-progress-of-file-to-s3-using-ruby-aws-sdk),

However since there is no clear solution to this I was wondering if there's a better/easier way (if one exists) of getting file upload progress with S3 using Ruby in 2018?

In my current setup I'm basically creating a new `Resource`, fetch my bucket and call `upload_file` but I haven't yet found any options for passing blocks which would help in yielding some sort of progress.

```
...
@connection = Aws::S3::Resource.new
@s3_bucket = @connection.bucket(bucket)
@s3_bucket.object(path).upload_file(data, {acl: 'public-read'})
...
```

Is there a way to do this using the newest sdk-for-ruby v3?

Any help (or even better a small example) would be great.

Comment: Seen the latest code in their repo and I think it is still the same. Why doesn't the existing answer work for you?

Comment: Because it’s “hacky” to say the least... We should normally be given a chunk argument much like in boto (python) or PHP... and it's so strange that this is not the case in Ruby... Plus the solution you are referring to is not a full example...

Comment: Well a full example can be provided if that is a problem, but there is no documented way as of now. I am checking if there are any alternatives

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The example Trevor gives in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12147709/153886 is not hacky from what I can see - just wiring things together. The SDK simply does not provide a feature for passing progress details on all operations. Plus, Trevor is the maintainer of the Ruby SDK at AWS so I trust his judgement.

Expanding on his example

```
bar = ProgressBar.create(:title => "Uploading action", :starting_at => 0, :total => file.size)
obj = s3.buckets['my-bucket'].objects['object-key']
obj.write(:content_length => file.size) do |writable, n_bytes|
  writable.write(file.read(n_bytes))
  bar.progress += n_bytes
end
```

If you want to have a progress block right in the `upload_file` method I believe you will need to open a PR to the SDK. It is not that strange that is not the case for Ruby (or for any other runtime) because, for example, there could be an optimisation in the HTTP client library that uses `IO.copy_stream` from your source `body` argument to the destination socket, which does not relay progress anywhere.